# Python file redirect give empty file

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code is used to convert the data from hexadecimal to binary works perfect but, but when I redirect the output to the file, the output file is empty

here is the code

```
for file in glob.glob("g1.txt.out"):
 print file
 myfile = open(file, "r")
 outfile= open( file + ".binary",'a+')

 for line in myfile:

  data_binary="{0:16b}".format(int(line, 16))
  print >> outfile,data_binary # redirect code.
```

Comment: why looping on a non-pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting the output of print, you can write directly to the output file:

```
with open("g1.txt.out", "r") as my_file, open("g1.txt.out.binary",'a+') as out_file:
    for line in my_file:
        data_binary = "{0:16b}\n".format(int(line, 16))
        out_file.write(data_binary)
```

Comment: you have to separate the data somehow, else your binary data consists of 1 line of 0 and 1s. `print` adds a linefeed: `data_binary = "{0:16b}\n".format(int(line, 16))` should do.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre updated the answer again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close you files, as io is buffered. Always remember to close all your open files to save data.

```
for file in glob.glob("g1.txt.out"):
    print file
    myfile = open(file, "r")
    outfile= open( file + ".binary",'a+')

    for line in myfile:

        data_binary="{0:16b}".format(int(line, 16))
        print >> outfile,data_binary # redirect code.
    myfile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

Or even better learn `with` statement, which will do it automatically.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()
    do something with data
```